# inject string into get request

Tags: python, pandas, api, request

I am trying to inject a specific string into a request in order to create an easier to use API. This is all for learning purposes.

I am working with python and jpyter notebooks. the below command works but I want to be able to modify it on the fly with string injection somehow..

### original working request

```
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=AMD&interval=5min&apikey=('alpha.txt')"
```

### New try

```
import requests
##this is the data I want to inject
atest = {'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=AMD&interval=5min'}
##New request attempting to use injection 
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={atest}&apikey=('alpha.txt')"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
```

it should show json stock data for amd as an end result to this command

Answer (score 0):

Try is using .format

```
import requests
##this is the data I want to inject
atest = {'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=AMD&interval=5min'}
##New request attempting to use injection 
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={0}&apikey=('alpha.txt')"
url = url.format(atest)
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
```

You can pass multiple parameters(strings) to .format function.